# Client App Verification

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, security

Im developing a Rails app that will contain a web front end as well as expose a service to a client app. This client app (for now being written in .Net) will just be sending data (not sensitive data, just statistics) to the service. Although this data will be tied to a user account on the site so they can view results online.

My question pertains to the best way to verify the user that downloaded the app to the website. I'm thinking of different ways to do it and here's what I've come up with:

-Have the user provide their login information (username/password) in the app and send that along with te data (most likely encrypted).
-When someone registers for an account, generate a key specifically for the client app and have them provide that when installing the app.

Is either of those a better option or is there some other way I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those do seem like the basic ways of handling the situation. Which one you choose to implement depends on whether a given copy of the client app is going to be used by just one user (in which case having the web app generate a key that is stored in the client makes more sense, since it can save the user the trouble of logging in every time they want to upload their data), or potentially by multiple users (in which case you probably want them to authenticate individually and on each use).

Comment: That makes sense. On top of that I should probably elaborate on the app a little. I'm thinking it will just run as a system tray app that monitors changes in a folder for a file. The app takes the file, parses it, and uploads the data to the database on the web. I just didn't know if someone has gone down that road an has some advice one way or another.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus I assume mean that the user gives their username & pass (hashed and salted client side) which is then compared to the corresponding hashed & salted pass on the server side.  The client then generates a keypair and sends the server a copy of it's public key.  That way you can encrypt and sign (confidentiality and authentication) the content.

Comment: @Daisetsu I was thinking about the problem at a more abstract level (user experience/design vs. implementation), but the process you describe does sound like a correct way to actually go about it.

Comment: @Daisetsu That's actually a good way to go about it. Although the data is in no case sensitive which will probably not need to be encrypted, the user information will definitely need to be.